# Как ускорить WebView?

Tags: java, android, webview

Есть сайт в нем есть раздел 3D прогулка созданная при помощи JS.
Так вот подключился к нему через **WebView**, но вот дело - есть тормоза, очень медленно двигается.

Можно ли как то ускорить (оптимизировать работу **WebView**)?

так же пытался таким путем не сработало:

```html
// Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        //metodi optimizacii
        mWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setSavePassword(true);
        webSettings.setSaveFormData(true);
        webSettings.setEnableSmoothTransition(true);





        // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Comment: WebView это обычный браузер в вашем телефоне, только "голый" , переопределив методы, конечно, вы можете отрубить некий функционал, чтобы он не исполнялся (показ картинок-рекламы-или вообще оставив статичную html без js) 
А так, это не нативка, чтобы его оптимизировать.

Comment: нужно оптимизировать js.

Comment: что можете предложить???п что сделать с jsŞ

Comment: так как код js не известен, то предложить ничего не могу кроме как выбросить эту затею - использовать webview и переписать это все нативно. Я понимаю, что это может быть достаточно сложно, но тут нужно выбирать - или скорость разработки, либо скорость исполнения.